# Python regex for Python function signatures

Tags: python, regex

I try to write a python regex, which matches the signature of simple python functions.
Like:

```
def _func1_(arg1, arg2):
```

I created this regex:

```
"def ([^\W\d]+\w*)(\(( *[^\W\d]+\w* *,? *)*\)):"
```

Unfortunately, this is not really good. In the argument list, spaces can be within variable names, and an unnecessary comma can be at the and of the argument list, in my regex. Can somebody help me out with the correct regex for this case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regular expressions are not parsers.

Comment: Why not [walk the AST](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html)?

Comment: The trailing comma is actually allowed by Python.

Comment: I know, but my task is this...

@9000 Interesting, but it really is, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a matter of fact, I recently wrote a simple regex for function header comments (To automatically format my homework for a CS class). Here's the gist of it:

```
"def (\w+)\s*\((.*?)\):"
```

For the parameters, I would forgo using re and instead use `str.split(',')` on capture group `1`. There's no need to make it more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: `def fn(a=(1, 2)):` is a valid definition. It needs to be more complicated.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Which part? The `re` portion of my answer still works perfectly fine. I can see how using `split(",")` on `a=(1,2)` would break, however.

Comment: @Ignacio: I'm sorry, forgot to mention, my task is simpler, maybe i wasn't clear. The argument list can only contain simple variable names like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

If you can import the function definitions, [walk AST](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html) or use [inspect](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec).

If you have more parsing to do beside signatures, consider [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) or [funcparselib](http://code.google.com/p/funcparserlib/).

If you still need to use regexs, bear with me.

```
import re

# Python identifiers start with a letter or _,
#and continue with these or digits. 
IDENT = '[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*'

# Commas between identifiers can have any amout of space on either side.
COMMA = '\s*,\s*'

# Parameter list can contain some positional parameters.
# For simplicity we ignore now named parameters, *args, and **kwargs.
# We catch the entire list.
PARAM_LIST = '\((' + IDENT+'?' + '(?:' + COMMA+IDENT + ')*'+ ')?\)'

# Definition starts with 'def', then identifier, some space, and param list.
DEF = 'def\s+(' + IDENT + ')\s*' + PARAM_LIST

ident_rx = re.compile(IDENT)
def_rx = re.compile(DEF)


def test(s):
    match = def_rx.match(s)
    if match:
        name, paramlist = match.groups()
        # extract individual params
        params = [x.group() for x in ident_rx.finditer(paramlist or '')]
        print s, name, params 
    else:
        print s, 'does not match'

test('def foo(a, b)')
test('def foo()')
test('def foo(a,b,c , d,  e)')
test('deff foo()')
test('def foo(a, 2b)')
```

Note that the above code cannot handle parameters with default values, `*args` or `**kwargs`, or the trailing comma, let alone things like `def foo(a, (b, c))` legal in Python 2. This all can be added, but the complexity will soar.

So, unless your case is rather simple (the code example above is borderline), see parser links above.